# Using Jquery in Razor View

Tags: jquery, .net, visual-studio, razor-pages

I'm stuck on a issue where I need to insert a jquery variable in a Razor View. For instance I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            pages: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Array)) ,
            singlePageMode: true
        };
        $("#pdfbox").flipBook(options);
    })
```

which gives an output:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            pages: ["http://localhost:651684/Document/GetPage?PageID=71184505-1.png","http://localhost:65184/Document/GetPage?PageID=71184505-2.png"] ,
            singlePageMode: true
        };
        $("#pdfbox").flipBook(options);
    })
```

To get it working ,I would have to add '{src:}' in the Array of pages like this:

```
pages:[
{src:"http://localhost:651684/Document/GetPage?PageID=71184505-1.png"},        
{src:"http://localhost:651684/Document/GetPage?PageID=71184505-1.png"}
]
```

But I cannot seem to do that. Is there a way to insert jquery in @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Array)). 
Please need Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array#map()` to return the array of objects needed

```
    var options = {
        pages: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Array)) ,
        singlePageMode: true
    };

    options.pages = options.pages.map(function(url){
       return { src: url };
    });

    $("#pdfbox").flipBook(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        pages: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Array) + ".map((u)=>{return {src: u };})") ,
        singlePageMode: true
    };
    $("#pdfbox").flipBook(options);
})
```

That turns into

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        pages: ["http://www.google.com","http://www.stackoverflow.com"].map((u)=>{return {src: u };}) ,
        singlePageMode: true
    };
    $("#pdfbox").flipBook(options);
})
```